# Ciclo switch con return

Tags: c++

Estoy desarrollando un menú con el uso de try/catch. El problema ocurre cuando el usuario introduce un argumento inválido en la función `miFuncion()` , como un caracter. Me he esforzado por simplificar el código que produce el error:

```
void miFuncion()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Ingrese valor de a: ";
    try
    {
        if( not( cin >> a  ) )
            throw invalid_argument("no es un entero");
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument& error)
    {
        cout << error.what() << endl;
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
        cin.clear();
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n a es un entero";    
}
int main()
{       
    int opcion;
    cout << "\n Ingrese valor para opcion: ";
    cin >> opcion;
    while( opcion >= 1 && opcion <= 3 )
    {
        switch( opcion )
        {
            case 1:
                miFuncion();
                break;
            //... Otros casos y default
        }
        cout << "\n Ingrese valor para opcion: ";           
        cin >> opcion;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Luego de que se atrapa el error y se regresa a main (con la función `return`) el ***programa finaliza***.

- ¿Por qué ocurre esto, si ya he aplicado `cin.ignore()`  y `cin.clear()` ?
- ¿Qué se puede hacer para que el ciclo while continúe normalmente?

Comment: Las excepciones, como su nombre indica, son para controlar casos excepcionales no para controlar el flujo del programa. Su cometido es hacer tareas de limpieza cuando el código llega a un estado irrecuperable, no para hacer tareas de redirección del flujo cuando el programa llega a un estado normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que invertir el orden de estas dos instrucciones:

```
cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
cin.clear();
```

Ante una lectura errónea, `cin` se bloquea hasta que se limpie el flag de error, cosa que se hace con `clear`. Mientras no se haga eso, la funcionalidad de `cin` está seriamente limitada.

Por otro lado, el uso que haces de la excepción es francamente perverso a la par que inutil. Las excepciones deben servir para controlar situaciones excepcionales y, francamente, reemplazar un `if` (el cual tampoco reemplazas porque lo tienes que poner igualmente) por una excepción resulta cuanto menos poco ortodoxo.

En el ejemplo que comentas las excepciones podrían usarse, por ejemplo, en una función cuya función fuese leer un entero, lanzando una excepción ante una lectura incorrecta. Por ejemplo:

```
int leerInt()
{
    int a;
    if( !(cin >> a) )
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
        throw invalid_argument("el valor introducido no es un entero");
    }

    return a;
}

void miFuncion()
{
    int a;

    while(true)
    {
      cout << "Ingrese valor de a: ";
      try
      {
        a = leerInt();
      }

      catch( std::invalid_argument const& error)
      {
        cout << "Error: " << error.what() << '\n';
        continue;
      }

      break;
    }

    cout << "\n a es un entero";    
}

int main()
{       
    int opcion;
    cout << "\n Ingrese valor para opcion: ";
    cin >> opcion;
    while( opcion >= 1 && opcion <= 3 )
    {
        switch( opcion )
        {
            case 1:
                miFuncion();
                break;
            //... Otros casos y default
        }
        cout << "\n Ingrese valor para opcion: ";           
        cin >> opcion;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

En este caso el uso de la excepción podría estar justificado ya que `leerInt` no dispone de mecanismos que permitan avisar ante una lectura incorrecta.